# Buy an app on mobile, but confirm (password) on desktop via email?

Tags: google-play-store

When I buy an app on my Android mobile, I am asked for the password of my Google account. I could tell it to remember my password forever, but actually I like that I have to confirm this action.

My password is quite a lengthy random string which I manage with a password manager on my (Linux) desktop. It is quite inconvenient to type it on my mobile.

I was wondering if there is a way to let Google send me an email when purchasing an app, which sends me to a confirmation page, which I can fill out on my desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I know of, why not:

- Install your password manager app on your phone (I use LastPass) and have it auto-fill your password (or copy/paste)
- If you are going to be purchasing the app from your phone and were going to your desktop anyways, instead just go to Google Play via your desktop and purchase it from there, and have it then download to your device

Comment: I trust my desktop more than I trust my phone. This is why I don't manage my passwords on my phone. But purchasing it via desktop seems fine!

Comment: I do it either way, I understand your dilemma, I will go via computer first if I have it up already.